# Match data entered with data in the database CAKEPHP

Tags: cakephp, loops, compare

I am stuck at the loop function of cakephp.
The logic is I need to compare the data entered by users with the data already in a table. I have two tables, one is `Bookings` and one is `Inventories_Bookings`. Below is my coding but it doesnot work. any help! Thanks

```
public function add2() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        foreach ($invbook as $invenbook)  
        {
            if ($this->request->data['Booking']['bookings_location'] == $invenbook['InventoriesBooking']['test'])
            {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The booking cannot be created'));
                $this->redirect(array('action' => 'add2'));
                debug($this->request->data['Booking']['bookings_location'] == $invenbook['InventoriesBooking']['test']);
            }
        }

        $this->Booking->create();
        $invbook = $this->Booking->InventoriesBooking->find('list',array('fields' => array('InventoriesBooking.id', 'InventoriesBooking.test')));
        $this->set(compact('invbook'));
    }
}
```

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? Do you get any errors?

Comment: step 0: ensure your debug mode is on or not..if not sure place Configure::write('debug', 2); inside your  add2 function.
step 1: debug the data entered by the users..i.e in your case it may be something like debug($this->request->data);
step 2: debug the data already in the table.. which i guess may be something like debug($invbook);
step 3: check if your comparison $this->request->data['Booking']['bookings_location'] == $invenbook['InventoriesBooking']['test'] is correct or not.
step 4: feedback your test results so that we can know what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a custom validation function for this.

You are able to create your own functions in the model, and from here you can access the database to do the lookup. If it matches you can return true.

[You can read about custom validation methods in the book.](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html#custom-validation-rules)

[There is an example of a rule like this using the db in the book.](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html#adding-your-own-validation-methods)
Quoted for great justice.

```
class User extends AppModel {

    public $validate = array(
        'promotion_code' => array(
            'rule'    => array('limitDuplicates', 25),
            'message' => 'This code has been used too many times.'
        )
    );

    public function limitDuplicates($check, $limit) {
        // $check will have value: array('promotion_code' => 'some-value')
        // $limit will have value: 25
        $existing_promo_count = $this->find('count', array(
            'conditions' => $check,
            'recursive' => -1
        ));
        return $existing_promo_count < $limit;
    }
}
```